# How can I select multiple TR elements in a table?

Tags: html-table, multi-select, tablerow

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td/>
     <td/>
     <td/>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td/>
     <td/>
     <td/>
  </tr>
  .....
</table>
```

This the table structure I have and I want to provide multi select feature on this table. User should be able to select multiple TR elements - very similar to  tag.
But I cannot use  because I want to add multiple span elements in each td in the above structure.

I thought of having an event capture on TR. But I am totally at loss as to how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Some of the other things I tried include adding a DIV directly inside TR - but that is incorrect. And adding a div inside the TD is of no use to me in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by selecting?

Comment: select... how? for what? like a file manager where each `<tr>` represents a file and clicking on it "selects" that file?

Comment: select as in - click on a bunch of TRs and they all remain highlighted and I have a right click menu on the table whose options will pick all data in the selected TRs

Comment: I'm guessing that you are trying to implement this select with JavaScript. Have you already tried some code and if so could you provide that to us? Thanks!

Comment: yes, I am using javascript. But, I am not really sure as to where I should even start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SlickGrid. It pretty much gives you that out of the box. It uses div instead of table, though. 
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Comment: I already have a table and TRs defined. To redo the entire code would be difficult for me at this point.

Comment: You could also try DataTables: http://www.datatables.net. I think it is possible to reuse an already populated table element with it. It comes with a lot of baggage just to support multi-select, though. I prefer the much more lightweight, modular and flexible approach of SlickGrid.

Comment: datatables looks suitable for my usecase here. Thankyou